# How to override the php.ini file settings in laragon?

Tags: php, laragon

When i upgrade my php version from 7.1 to 7.2 there is new folder include in

> **c:\laragon\bin\php**

which is right. But when i edit the **php.ini** file and enable **openssl** and other extension, save it and restart than it will override by the previous php.ini. It happens to two three times. I think there is a global php.ini file. If it has then how can we override this **php.ini** files with other versions **php.ini**?

If anyone knows please describe it or give me suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the response

> I think there is a global php.ini file

..is wrong. Please change anything (extension) in the specific php directory that you will use. This is the php directory of laragon on my local, if I will use php version 8, then I change the php.ini file in "php-8.0.8-nts-Win32-vs16-x64".
[image]

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just installed php incorrectly in laragon, check the folder "C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.3.21\ext" and if this folder is empty then that would mean there is no extension, even after activation it will not change the "php.ini" file. I had the same problem.